Elements disappear after I move them


Vertices, edges and faces just  deleted after I move them with G (I know I’m noob)

They are deleted or hidden by other geometry where you have moved them behind? At least I can see connecting edges to the background, so there is not everything deleted...

i assume you have a subdivision modifier on that object?
So you can either disable that modifier in the viewport by clicking here (see below) or on cage (see below)

